# How do I assert the result is an integer in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I would like to be able test that a result is an integer (1,2,3...) where the function could return any number, e.g.:

```
$new_id = generate_id();
```

I had thought it would be something like:

```
$this->assertInstanceOf('int', $new_id);
```

But I get this error:

**Argument #1 of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertInstanceOf() must be a class or interface name**

Comment: Since generally ids shouldn't be zero, you'll probably also want to check that: 0 < $new_id in cases like this.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
$this->assertInternalType("int", $id);
```

**Edit**: As of [PHPUnit 8](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.0/assertions.html?highlight=assertIsInt), the answer is:

```
$this->assertIsInt($id);
```

Comment: @Andrew I don't have environment to test it. Could you please try and share results.

Comment: @Andrew you probably figured it out by now. "34" doesn't work

Comment: Because type of "34" actually is string and it is normal

Comment: `assertIsInt` method was added in version [7.5](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.5/assertions.html#assertisint)

Answer (score 28):

I prefer using the official PHPUnit class constants.

PHPUnit [v5.2](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.2/src/Framework/Constraint/IsType.php#L24):

```php
use PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsType as PHPUnit_IsType;

// ...

$this->assertInternalType(PHPUnit_IsType::TYPE_INT, $new_id);
```

Or latest which at the moment of writing is [v7.0](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/7.0/src/Framework/Constraint/IsType.php#L23):

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\IsType;

// ...

$this->assertInternalType(IsType::TYPE_INT, $new_id);
```

Answer (score 17):

Original answer is given below for posterity, but I would strongly recommend using `assertInternalType()` as suggested in other answers.

---

Original answer:

Simply use assertTrue with is_int().

```
$this->assertTrue(is_int($new_id));
```

Comment: When creating tests, it's advised to go with the most specific test case. This will create better more descriptive errors.

Answer (score 6):

I think better use this construction:

```
$this->assertThat($new_id, $this->logicalAnd(
    $this->isType('int'), 
    $this->greaterThan(0)
));
```

because it will check not only the type of $new_id variable, but will check if this variable is greater than 0 (assume id cannot be negative or zero) and this is more strict and secure.

Answer (score 5):

As of PHPUnit 8, The other approaches are now deprecated, `assertInternalType()` will now throw this error and fail:

> assertInternalType() is deprecated and will be removed in PHPUnit 9. Refactor your test to use assertIsArray(), assertIsBool(), assertIsFloat(), assertIsInt(), assertIsNumeric(), assertIsObject(), assertIsResource(), assertIsString(), assertIsScalar(), assertIsCallable(), or assertIsIterable() instead.

It is now recommended to use `assertIsNumeric()` or `assertIsInt()` for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I included it in the top answer as well, so it's seen straight away.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for people wondering how to make sure that the result is EITHER an integer or a string of integers.  (The issue appears in some comments):

```
$this->assertEquals( 1 , preg_match( '/^[0-9]+$/', $new_id ),
    $new_id . ' is not a set of digits' );
```

Here we make sure preg_match returns a '1', where preg_match is testing that all string characters are digits.